# Figuring out ellipsoid-ellipsoid collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics

I've been working on collision detection code for a project, and I'm trying to figure out the method to use to detect collisions between objects. Since I use ellipsoids to test against level geometry, I'd like to use them for collisions between objects as well. The problem is figuring out exactly how. One method I've seen converts the ellipsoids to a sphere and an axis-aligned ellipsoid, which looks like a great solution, but the method involves finding eigenvectors and other advanced stuff that I don't really understand (yet) and would rather not have to implement.

It should be easy to convert the ellipsoids to a sphere and a skewed ellipsoid by applying a series of affine transformations. I've read that a skewed ellipse is still elliptical, so the skewing is equivalent to a rotation and a scaling, and I assume that the same principle applies to ellipsoids. However, I'm not sure how to determine the rotation and axis lengths of the new ellipse. If I knew that, it would be easy to make the ellipsoid axis-aligned.
After that, I'm hoping to be able to perform a sweep test, but I'm not sure how efficiently it can be done, and I haven't figured out the equations to use yet, although I could likely figure those out with a little work.

I'm also considering working with other collision shapes if ellipsoids don't work out, but it would be really nice to be able to use the same shapes for object-world and object-object collisions.

Comment: If you distort one of the ellipses to a sphere, you may be able to use  [Circle-ellipse intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-EllipseIntersection.html)

Comment: There is a discussion thread on ellipse-ellipse intersection [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/2ellipses)

Comment: After some more research into the topic, it looks like proper ellipsoid-ellipsoid collision detection is too complex to be practical. I've moved on to using capsules, which work fairly nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is complicated.

There is a paper titled [An Algebraic Approach to Continuous Collision Detection for Ellipsoids](http://hal.inria.fr/hal-00646511/PDF/CCD.3.0.pdf)

There is another paper [here](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionOfEllipsoids.pdf) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionOfEllipsoids.pdf)) from [this site](http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Intersection/Intersection.html) that describes an algorithm mathematically.

Matlab script [Are Two Ellipsoids in Contact?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32172-are-two-ellipsoids-in-contact-algebraic-separation-condition-for-ellipsoids/content/Algebraic%20Separation%20Condition/Algebraic_Separation_Condition.m), which references the aforementioned paper.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER: This method will not work in certain circumstances. I found this out after posting my answer. However, the results might be good enough for simple use-cases which is why I'm leaving this answer here.**

My method return false in the case as shown in the image below.

[image]

**Original Answer:**

I've seen this question multiple times now, but I managed to come up with an extremely easy solution:

To check collision between two spheres we usually want to use their radius and see if it is smaller than the distance between the two spheres.

With ellipsoids we can try to do the same. However, the radius is different all over the ellipsoid. But this is fairly easy to achieve, we just need to know the direction of which we want to get our radius.

```
float EllipsoidRadius(VECTOR ellipsoidRadius, VECTOR direction)
{
    direction /= ellipsoidRadius;
    normalize(direction);
    return length(direction * ellipsoidRadius);
    // The * is just a multiplication
}
```

We know our direction, this is simply the position of one of our ellipsoids minus the position of the other. We can use this direction to get the radius of both of our ellipsoids since the radius will always be equal on opposite sides (As long as we have axis aligned ellipsoids).

```
bool EllipsoidIntersects(POINT positionA, VECTOR sizeA, POINT positionB, VECTOR sizeB)
{
    VECTOR direction = positionA - positionB;
    float distance = length(direction);

    float radiusA = EllipsoidRadius(sizeA, direction);
    float radiusB = EllipsoidRadius(sizeB, direction);

    return distance < radiusA + radiusB;
}
```

Now that we know the radius of our two ellipsoids we can just use the good old sphere collision check to see if they collide.